# Stylus create multiple styles while changing only 1 array

Tags: css, node.js, stylus

I would like to be able to define my tags, fantasy, realism, and mystery as colors:

```
tagsHash = {
   fantasy: #4286f4,
   realism: #779954,
   mystery: #91184a
}

#container
   createTags(tagsHash)
```

and then have it produce code like this:

```
#container
  &[data-tag='fantasy']
    applyStyles(fantasy)
  &[data-tag='realism']
    applyStyles(realism)
  &[data-tag='mystery']
    applyStyles(mystery)

  // combination styles
  &[data-tag='fantasy'][data-tag='realism']
    applyStyles(blend(fantasy, realism))
  &[data-tag='realism'][data-tag='mystery']
    applyStyles(blend(realism, mystery))
  &[data-tag='mystery'][data-tag='fantasy']
    applyStyles(blend(mystery, fantasy))
```

I would like for it to work with arbitrary number of tags with arbitrary colors. New tags would automatically create the needed selectors. Is this possible, and if not what's the closest I can get to it so that adding a new a new tag needs the least amount of changes possible?

What I got so far:

```
foo = {
  fantasy: #4286f4,
  realism: #779954,
  mystery: #91184a
}

applyStyles(c)
  .name
    color c

#container
  for key, value in foo
    &[data-tag={key}]
      applyStyles(value)
```

This works great. Produces exactly what I want. I then try to produce the combination. But does not work:

```
#container
  for key, value in foo
    &[data-tag={key}]
      applyStyles(value)

    for key2, value2 in foo
      unless key1 === key2
        &[data-tag*={key}][data-tag*={key2}]
          applyStyles(blend(value, value2))
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following solution (care the ident of the lines and additional information at the end):

```
foo = {
  fantasy: #4286f4,
  realism: #779954,
  mystery: #91184a
}

createTags(tags)
  for key, value in foo
    &[data-tag=\"{key}\"]
      applyStyles(value)
      for key2, value2 in foo
        unless key == key2
          &[data-tag=\"{key2}\"]
            applyStyles(blend(rgba(value, 0.5), value2))

applyStyles(c)
  .name
    color c

#containers
  createTags(foo)
```

... which gives the following CSS output:

```
#container[data-tag="fantasy"] .name {
  color: #4286f4;
}
#container[data-tag="fantasy"][data-tag="realism"] .name {
  color: #5d90a4;
}
#container[data-tag="fantasy"][data-tag="mystery"] .name {
  color: #6a4f9f;
}
#container[data-tag="realism"] .name {
  color: #779954;
}
#container[data-tag="realism"][data-tag="fantasy"] .name {
  color: #5d90a4;
}
#container[data-tag="realism"][data-tag="mystery"] .name {
  color: #84594f;
}
#container[data-tag="mystery"] .name {
  color: #91184a;
}
#container[data-tag="mystery"][data-tag="fantasy"] .name {
  color: #6a4f9f;
}
#container[data-tag="mystery"][data-tag="realism"] .name {
  color: #84594f;
}
```

Now you can add more tags to the `foo` with an color and convert the stylus script to CSS.

**Additional notes to your provided code:**

- The [`blend`](http://stylus-lang.com/docs/bifs.html#blendtop-bottom) function only works in case the first color has an alpha value lower than 1.
- The operator `===` isn't valid: [see this list on stylus documentation](http://stylus-lang.com/docs/operators.html#operator-precedence).

**Some more information (for new users on [stylus](http://stylus-lang.com/)):**

You can automatically re-compile the CSS file with the [`-w` or `--watch`](http://stylus-lang.com/docs/executable.html) option:

```
stylus -w stylus-file.styl
```